# Enable copy paste option in CKEditor source mode

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Trying to enable copy paste option in CKEditor source mode,
for example
1. select some text in source mode
2. right click on the text or do CTRL+C to copy the text
3. again right click or do CTRL+V to paste the copied text

In my case in source mode it doesn't copy the selected text to clip board and it doesn't fire paste events as well,tried debugging clipboard paste event

can someone please help on this how i can check why its not firing the event in source mode. but works/fires the event in WYSIWYG mode.

Also is there any way i can debug clipboard plugin.js file, tried putting "debuger;" but doesn't stop there also doesnt load in developer tools

No errors in console 
No customization on CKEditor 4.5.7 version

Comment: Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Any help on this